# Importing a variable from dynamically imported component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module, next.js

I have a (Map) component dynamically imported to my page.

`const Map = dynamic(() => import('../components/Mapcomp'), { ssr: false, })`

From that component I also want to import a variable.

```
const [taskImg, setTaskImg] = useState(null);


export {taskImg};
```

The component is dynamically imported because otherwise I get a `window is not defined` error, and this is the solution for that.
Same with the variable. If I want to import it I get the above error.
But I need to use the `taskImg` variable in this page.
How can I do that?

Mapcomp:

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, useMap, Marker, Popup, 
ImageOverlay } from 'react-leaflet'
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Head from "next/head"
import { LatLngBounds } from 'leaflet';

const Map = () => {


  const [userPos, setUserPos] = useState(null)
  const [taskPos, setTaskPos] = useState(null)
  const [task, setTask] = useState()
  const [taskImg, setTaskImg] = useState(null);


  const bounds = new LatLngBounds([81.505, -0.09], [50.773941, -84.12544])

useEffect(() => {
  
  function getRandomTask(arr) {

const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);

const item = arr[randomIndex];

return item;
}

const tasks = [
  "boller",
  "placeholder"
];



setTask(getRandomTask(tasks));

},[])

useEffect(() => {

  if(task == "boller"){
    console.log("boller")
    setTaskImg("/sf2.jpg")
  } else if(task == "placeholder") {
    console.log("placeholder")
  }

},[task])

return (
<>
    <Head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
        crossorigin=""/>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
    </Head>

    <MapContainer 
    className='absolute h-[750px] w-[750px] left-[45%] top-[80px] bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-[#738aaf]'
    center={[71.505, -40.09]} zoom={3} scrollWheelZoom={true} noWrap={true}>
    <ImageOverlay
      url="/allmaphres.png"
      bounds={bounds}
      opacity={1}
      zIndex={10}
    />
  </MapContainer>
</>
);
}

export default Map;
```

page (mapcomp is rendered here):

```
import { memo, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import Head from "next/head";
const Map = dynamic(() => import('../components/Mapcomp'), {
  ssr: false,
})

const All = () => {

return (
  <>
<Navbar />

<div className="bg-white w-[500px] h-[100vh]">
  <div className="task border-4 border-red-500 h-[250px]">
    {/* taskImg && <img src={taskImg}/> */}
  </div>
  <div className="flex justify-center gap-[200px] text-xl">
    <span>Tasks:</span>
    <span>Points:</span>
  </div>
  <div className="flex justify-center gap-[240px] text-xl">
    <span>X</span>
    <span>X</span>
  </div>

</div>

<Map />
<Footer />
   </>   
  );
}

export default All;
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "import a variable". You pass these variables as props to the component. And `useState` must be called inside a component, not at the top level of a module.

Comment: I need to render a div depending on what the state currently is, i can't put it as a prop.

Comment: So? Sure you can pass in that state as a prop. Please post the full code necessary to reproduce your problem, that includes the code of the component that you want to render (`Mapcomp`) as well as the code of the component where you want to render it.

Comment: I edited the post with all the necessary code.

Comment: Given the `Map` does not do anything with the `taskImg` and `setTaskImg`, you should place that state and all the effects using it inside the `All` component. Possibly wrap it in a  [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html), but still it should go in `All`.

Comment: "*The component is dynamically imported because otherwise I get a `window is not defined error`*" - I doubt that's the solution for that error. This sounds more like a problem with leaflet.js, not something that should be solved with a dynamic import.

Comment: For some reason I thought it would be easier to implement these states in the Map component, but now I don't really know why. Thank you for helping.

I'll have a state which will depend on the current `task` (in the All component rn), and I will need to get that state in the Map component. I will display a marker on the map depending on the state. How could I implement that?

Comment: Just pass that state as a prop to the map, then have the map figure out how to display the marker.

Answer (score 1):

You can't export a state to another component you either need to use a state management library like `redux` or create a context which make the state available for all the other components

Comment: What do you mean "or create a context which make the state available for all the other components"? I don't understand this part.

Comment: Context API is a react future, it's useful to share a common used data which many components are rely on and much more read more about it here
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext